# Unable to use FFMPEG to transcode video

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

I am getting the below error while transcoding videos automatically using nzbtomedia (https://github.com/clinton-hall/nzbToMedia/).

Transcoder returned:b"Unknown encoder 'libx264'\n" has failed

How do I install this encoder?

Raspbain (Raspberry PI)

Additional Info:

FFMPEG Version

```
ffmpeg version N-96192-g2ff687c17f Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
configuration: 
libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
libavcodec     58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
libavdevice    58.  9.101 / 58.  9.101
libavfilter     7. 69.101 /  7. 69.101
libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
```

ffmpeg -encoders | grep 264

```
ffmpeg version N-96192-g2ff687c17f Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.101 / 58.  9.101
  libavfilter     7. 69.101 /  7. 69.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
 V..... h264_v4l2m2m         V4L2 mem2mem H.264 encoder wrapper (codec h264)
```

Comment: How did you install ffmpeg? can you paste `ffmpeg -version` and maybe also do `ffmpeg -encoders | grep 264`

Comment: @MattiasWadman I've updated the question with the output for the above commands

Comment: Your ffmpeg seems to not be built with libx264 support. How did you install ffmpeg? . If your using  ubuntu i think you should be able to install the official ffmpeg package and get libx264 support. Just `apt-get install ffmpeg`.

Comment: Oh! My bad. I am using Raspbain. Its a PI. I've corrected the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you followed this [ancient wiki guide](https://github.com/clinton-hall/nzbToMedia/wiki/Transcoder#linux) that had you compile ffmpeg without libx264 enabled.

I'm guessing you are using Raspbian Buster which the official repository currently offers FFmpeg 4.1.4 with libx264 enabled. So uninstall the ffmpeg you compiled:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg
sudo make uninstall
```

Then install ffmpeg from the repository:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Now when you run `ffmpeg` it should show `--enable-libx264` in the output.

You may also see `--enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal` which will allow hardware decoding/encoding of:

- H.264 encoding (`-c:v h264_omx`) & decoding (`-c:v h264_mmal`)
- MPEG-4 Part 2 video encoding (`-c:v mpeg4_omx`) & decoding (`-c:v mpeg4_mmal`)
- MPEG-2 video decoding (`-c:v mpeg2_mmal`)
- VC-1 decoding (`-c:v vc1_mmal`)

Comment: Now I get this error: ```b'[matroska,webm @ 0xe9f320] Invalid EBML number size tag 0x0d at pos 1974965704 (0x75b795c8)\n'```

Comment: @MathewParet More context is needed to provide any suggestions. Use a pastebin site to show your command and the complete log and give the link in a comment.

Comment: FFMPeg is called by nzbtomedia. This is what I can see in the nzbtomedia log - https://pastebin.com/BYbqXTs8 The command used (found using ps -ef) is in https://pastebin.com/kBKTiwxf

Comment: @MathewParet 1) The nzbtomedia log is not important, but the ffmpeg command is useful info. However, it is only half of the required info. I need the log from that ffmpeg command. 2) Does the output file play normally regardless of the error (or warning–I'm not sure which it is yet without the log)？ If yes, then ignore the earning.

Comment: The output definitely plays without any issue.

Comment: @MathewParet You can ignore the message.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Raspbian ffmpeg package is lacking libx264 support. I would suggest try changing the VCODEC nzbToMedia configuration to use "h264_v4l2m2m" or install a ffmpeg version with libx264 support.

Here is forum thread discussing the lack libx264 support issue https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=184425